# Base Presenter Test class using Mockito and Kotlin - working around Generic type erasure

Tags: android, kotlin, mockito

I'm trying to write a base test class with generics to reduce boilerplate code. It's specifically for testing (MVP) Presenters and I'm using Mockito to mock the View interface. E.g. something like this (simplified):

```
abstract class BasePresenterTest<V: BaseView, P: BasePresenter<V>> {

    @Mock
    lateinit var mockView: V

    lateinit var presenter: P

    @Before
    open fun setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)
    }

    // ...
}
```

This is a problem because type erasure means Mockito can't mock the concrete View type passed in the generic parameter. Attempting to run such a test will produce a `java.lang.ClassCastException: BaseView$MockitoMock$1481956224 cannot be cast to ConcreteView` at runtime.

My current workaround is to add an abstract function to return the View Class so it can be mocked directly in the base class:

```
abstract class BasePresenterTest<V: BaseView, P: BasePresenter<V>> {

    lateinit var mockView: V

    lateinit var presenter: P

    abstract fun getViewClass(): Class<V>

    @Before
    open fun setUp() {
        mockView = Mockito.mock(getViewClass())
    }

    // ...
}
```

This means more boilerplate code in the concrete test class which somewhat defeats the purpose of the base test class altogether. It's also the classic Java workaround to generic type erasure. I'm wondering if there's a a better way to do this with Kotlin? (I was thinking reified generic type parameters somehow, but they only apply to inline functions.)

Answer (score 0):

Can't think of a better way in Kotlin, but I'd argue you should rethink your design decision and eventually use composition to move any code you might want to share amongst different presenters into a separate class.

In order to still keep the ease of calling through, you could make this common presenter class a delegate of the specific class, like so:

```
class MyCommonPresenter : CommonPresenter {
    ...
}

class MySpecificPresenter internal constructor(common: CommonPresenter) 
    : CommonPresenter by common {
    constructor() = this(MyCommonPresenter())
    ...
}
```

and then you'd just write a test for `MyCommonPresenter` and treat it as a mockable dependency for `MySpecificPresenter` tests.